# Can I enter Serbia if I am travelling with a wound?

Tags: airlines, health

I am an Indian citizen, planning to go to Belgrade via Dubai at the end of September. Recently, I got a cut on the top of my foot, no surgery but the wound is open.

I heard stories that I would not be allowed to board a flight with such a wound. It that true?

1) Can I travel with an open wound and would I need to carry a medical certificate from my doctor in India?

2) Since my connecting flight is in Dubai, is there any chance I would be being denied boarding the Belgrade flight?

3) I am travelling to speak at an InfoSec conference; if there is a problem, would conference officials help me to get permission to board?

Comment: As long as the wound is properly bandaged/covered I really don't see how/why you would be denied boarding for this reason. of course standard rules for passports and visa still apply. Conference organisers usually don't have much to say (though an invitation letter may be needed for visas in some situations).

Comment: Depending on how recent the surgery and the extent of the wound you may be more at risk of blood clots forming which could travel to your lungs and block the blood flow or cause thrombosis. Open wounds are also vulnerable to infection. You should seek medical advice.

Comment: the local doctor in india advised i m safe for travel ,and within india with same wound i was able to travel and all airlines allowed me ,With respective to international its mixed review from people ,so seeking help here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two potential problems: with the airlines and with immigration.

With regard to the airlines, if the captain of a flight feels you are not healthy to fly, they may unilaterally ask you to be removed from the flight. Pilots are in general not medical experts. I can only imagine that this would be a problem if you boarded the flight with your foot bleeding all over the place, causing a mess and exposing other passengers to infection. Bandage the wound cleanly and cover it with a sock and closed toed shoe so people can't see it. The captain will never know, let alone care.

Immigration authorities sometimes deny entry to people who are sick, either because they have communicable diseases or because they might be a drain on the country's health system. http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/entering-serbia-requirements indicates that Serbia is only concerned about people coming from epidemic areas. You should be fine on this front. Again, I would keep it covered. They won't know and they won't care.

In summary, I see no reason why this wound would prevent you from traveling if you keep it clean, bandaged, and covered. Carrying a doctor's certificate couldn't hurt and may be helpful in the extremely remote chance that you encounter problems.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer, The solution worked.Adding to the answer serbian officials just asked fit for fly certificate with any local doctor seal[india/origin country]. without fit for fly certificate i was able to fly safely.